# SQL function: use column 1 and column 2 to give column 3

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

Looking to write a function where I can call from any two columns in my table, to get the resulting column in the same table. 
Table: Acme
Columns: CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, EmailAdress, MailingAddress, City, State, Zip

Can I get EmailAddress from just FirstName and Last Name?
Can I get Zip from CustomerID and City?

What I have so far for EmailAddress:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnEmailAddress
(@LastName varchar (255), @FirstName varchar (255))

RETURNS table

RETURN (SELECT EmailAddress
FROM Acme
WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName);
```

END

So the following would give me brenda.chen@gmail.com:
EXEC fnEmailAddress ('Brenda'+'Chen')

But it doesn't work :(

Comment: what's wrong with your inline function?

Comment: The suspense is incredible! When will you add a question to your post?

Comment: @McNets: don't know what an inline function is.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint @HABO!

Comment: Revised my original question. Maybe easier to understand what I need? I think SQL can do it...I just can't figure out how!

Comment: (1) `FUNCTION` doesn't use `EXEC`, it uses `SELECT columnblabla FROM functionblabla('ducks', 'robbers')`. What uses `EXEC` is `PROCEDURE`. (2) Your function above works when I use `SELECT`, does that solve your issue? Or something still remains? Note in my answer, "arms" would represent last and first names, while "legs" represent customer ID and city, that works for you or are you looking for having 2 parameters instead of 4?

Comment: @KtX2SkD that was it! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a function that can adapt to several possibilities of input combinations, because what columns you will have ready as input might differ in each function call. If so:

1. Clearly, your function must have as many parameters as column possibilities you have, i.e. for any column that can possibly become a "column 1" or "column 2", add a parameter.
2. Since you have many parameters, you need to decide which ones are to be used, or if the inputs are irrational to begin with. For example:

   - What to do if you have 4 out of 4 parameters provided? Refuse to work? Or can the function adapt to that?
   - What if parameters 1 and 4 are provided but your function isn't meant to work with that? It's meant to work with 1 + 2 or 3 + 4 for example.
3. Lastly, choose one of either:

   - Set any unnecessary inputs to `NULL`, then query once with a `WHERE` clause that auto-passes any `NULL` inputs (*example: `WHERE COL1 = ISNULL(@PAR1, COL1) AND COL2 = ISNULL(@PAR2, COL2)`, needs more logic for `NULL`able columns*),
   - Or, utilizing `IF`/`ELSE` commands to switch between several different queries (*different queries is probably maintenance headache, so avoid when possible*).

Below is an example based on something I already have, although it uses the `IF`/`ELSE` approach. Try to do `NULL`/`ISNULL` instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SomeWackoName]
    (@FirstArm tinyint, @SecondArm tinyint, @FirstLeg tinyint, @SecondLeg tinyint)
RETURNS @Results TABLE(
      [Value] varchar(60)
) AS
BEGIN

    -- For input, we need both arms, or both legs. It is acceptable to provide three inputs.
    -- It is unacceptable to provide all four inputs (confusing), or failing to provide any full pair (like one input, or two unpaired inputs).
    DECLARE @Validator tinyint = CASE WHEN @FirstArm + @SecondArm IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + CASE WHEN @FirstLeg + @SecondLeg IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 2 END
    IF @Validator NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 2 RETURN --THROW 50000, 'INCORRECT INPUT WHYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY WHYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY', 0;

    -- Depending on input provided, decide how to behave.
    IF @Validator = 1
        INSERT INTO @Results SELECT 'I GOT THE ARMS. POPULATE WITH LEGS!!'
    ELSE IF @Validator = 2
        INSERT INTO @Results SELECT 'I GOT THE LEGS. POPULATE WITH ARMS!!'

    -- Return results.
    RETURN

END
```

Comment: Thank you KtX2SkD.  I don't need the capability for many column combinations just yet. At this time is just column1 + column = column3. Using CASE and + along with 0 ELSE 1 is something I will have to earn more about! Thank you!!

Comment: Revised my original question. Maybe easier to understand what I need? I think SQL can do it...I just can't figure out how!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnEmailAddress
(
 @LastName varchar (255)=null, @FirstName varchar (255)=null, 
 @streetNumber varchar(255)=null,@streetname varchar (255)=null
)
RETURNS table
Select case when @firstname+@lastname is not null then EMail Else LastName End Column3
from person 
where                                                                    
(
case when @firstname+@lastname is not null                               
     then case when FirstName=@firstname and LastName=@lastname
               then 1 else 0 End
     when @StreetNumber+@streetname is not null 
     then case when StreetName=@Streetname and StreetNumber=@streetNumber
               then 1 Else 0 End 
End 
)=1
```

The function should have 4 input parameters, pass first two or the last two parameters only.

CASE in the select statement will get 'Email' or 'LastName' depending upon input parameter null or not.

Similarly, CASE in the where statement will choose which filter should apply depending upon input parameter null or not, and results will be fetched based on that.

Comment: Thank you JayaPrakash! CASE is too much for this one as I would want first+last=email OR number+street=lastname. Basically I just want column1+column2 = column3 all from the same database. I will change tables or create tables depending on who I give the function to.

Comment: Do you mean column name or table name will be passed|changed dynamically @brenda chen

Comment: Table. I will make a table with mix of needed columns for each need (there aren't many)